# Batch rename default.html to index.html in Terminal

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, file-rename, batch-rename

How do I batch rename these file names in OS X Terminal?

```
default.html
about/default.html
gallery/team/default.html
...
```

To:

```
index.html
about/index.html
gallery/team/index.html
..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
find . -name 'default.html' -execdir mv '{}' index.html \;
```

With `-execdir` the file is renamed in the dir where it was found.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `rename` comes in handy here. Try this:

```
find . -name default.html | xargs rename 's/default/index/'
```

Edit: I tested this on Linux; I'm not sure whether OS X has `rename`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find` command with `-exec` option:

```
find . -name 'default.html' -exec bash -c 'echo mv "$1" "${1%/*}/index.html"' _ '{}' \;
```

Once satisfied with the output, you can remove `echo` before `mv`.